# I lose access to my IBOutlets when making view controller new detail view controller

Tags: objective-c, ios, uisplitviewcontroller, iboutlet

I have an iPad master-detail where the main detail controller is a navigation controller and depending on the table row (in the master view controller) selected, I may or may not replace the view controller managed by the detail navigation controller.

This seems to work fine, except that I lose access to the new detail view controller's IBOutlets when this move is made.

Here's me switching the navigation controller's view controller:

```
CustomerDetailViewController *subview = [[CustomerDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CustomerDetailViewController" bundle:nil];            
[subview setTitle:@"Testing"];
AppDelegate *app = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
app.splitViewController.delegate = subview;
[app.detailNavigationController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:subview, nil]];
[subview setData:[custData objectForKey:@"name"]];
```

custData is an NSDictionary containing my view information.  Here is the setData command:

```
- (void)setData:(NSDictionary *)cust {

    NSLog(@"%@\n", [cust valueForKey:@"name"]);
    self.nameLabel.text = [cust valueForKey:@"name"];
    NSLog(@"%@\n", self.nameLabel.text);
}
```

So what happens is, subview becomes the new view controller but the label does not get changed - however, those two log commands are executed.  The label is synthesized and wired up using IB and works if I push subview as a new view controller instead of replace it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say, the view is not yet initialized. Outlets are first connected in the `viewDidLoad` method. Try putting a log statement in the `viewDidLoad` to find out, which one gets called first.

If the `viewDidLoad` is called after your `setData` method, you can only set a local variable of the `CustomerDetailViewController` which is then read by `viewDidLoad` which sets the label accordingly.

Comment: You are correct - viewDidLoad is occurring after setData.  However, I am init'ing that view prior to calling setData and assigning it as my detailViewController prior to the setData call as well.  Any idea on when the view may be loading?  Also - the title is being set correctly as it shows on the navigationViewController.

Comment: In any case - I have set `NSDictionary *cust` as an instance variable, set it with a custom init and am setting the labels in `viewDidLoad` as per your recommendation, and all is well.  Cheers.

Comment: I guess the view controller's title is handled different from other UI elements like `UILabel`s etc. Instantiating a view *controller* is also separated from the loading of its *view* (which is essentially something else, see the MVC pattern)

Comment: Yeah, I think that the constructor name `initWithNibName` - since the nib is essentially the view - confused me into thinking that you are initing the controller with the view simultaneously, but I guess  `initWithNibName` just ties the two together logically and doesn't actually initialize the view as well.